# CLion "This file does belojng to project target..."

Tags: makefile, clion

Why is CLion not recognizing mpi_heated_plate.c as part of the mpi target? All files are in the same directory as the Makefile. Clion recognizes the mpi target and can build and run. I've invalidated caches, reloaded the Makefile, and even deleted the project (.idea) and its still not loading insights. Below is my Makefile.

```
CC=gcc
MPICC=mpicc
CFLAGS= -Wall -g3 -pedantic -std=c11

all: serial omp mpi

serial: serial_heated_plate.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) serial_heated_plate.c -o serial_heated_plate.exe

mpi: mpi_heated_plate.c
    $(MPICC) $(CFLAGS) mpi_heated_plate.c -o mpi_heated_plate.exe

omp: omp_heated_plate.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fopenmp omp_heated_plate.c -o omp_heated_plate.exe

clean:
    rm -rf serial_heated_plate.exe
    rm -rf omp_heated_plate.exe
    rm -rf mpi_heated_plate.exe
```